# flutter devicePixelRatio

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how does flutter calculate `devicePixelRatio` for each device? 
for example:  
***pixel xl***:  
resolution: **1440*2560 px** 
 
device pixel ratio  **3.5** 
*screen size : **5.5 inch*** 
on the other hand 
 
**Nexus 6**:
resolution: **1440*2560 px** 
 
device pixel ratio  **3.5** 
*screen size : **6.0 inch***

both devices have different screen size however both devices have the same `devicePixelRatio` ??

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the different displays have different pixel dimensions. So that you can have the same amount of pixels on different sized displays.

Comment: Same number of pixels with different screen sizes leads to different pixel denisty with different pixel dimensions so it should lead to different device pixel ratio . In Android you can calculate the the scaling factor of the dp unit but in flutter I can't understand how scaling done . This issue really bothers me when use hard coded dimensions . because the behavior is not consistent across devices .